# The wind Field effect is not applying to my cloth plane

Tags: modifiers, objects, physics

I realise this is a common issue but I tried a lot of things and didn't manage to find a solution. I am new to the software and sorry for my ignorance.
Like a lot of people before, I am trying to create some sort of flag moving with the wind. I actually managed to render one version with the flag moving, and then tried to change the pinning of my flag to get a different effect.
After that, the flag stopped reacting to the wind (I didn't pin the whole flag)

I am using blender 2.79 and am looking for a solution.[image: screenshot with plane parameters]

[image: screenshot of wind parameters]

Comment: Have you deleted the cache of the previous simulation?

Comment: If by deleting the cache you mean free the bake and bake again, yes I have!